# Trying to read different gas levels with MQ2 Gas Sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, library, pins

I found a link on how to connect MQ-2 Gas Sensor to Arduino Uno.

http://electronicsprojectshub.com/how-to-connect-mq2-gas-sensor-to-arduino/

After I bought all the parts and tried it out, the sensor gave me this in the serial monitor

> Ro: 10.81 kohm
>
> LPG:0.00ppm    CO:0.00ppm    SMOKE:0.00ppm
>
> LPG:0.00ppm    CO:0.00ppm    SMOKE:0.00ppm

and so on.

Here is the code I used

```
#include <MQ2.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16,2);
int Analog_Input = A0;
int lpg, co, smoke;
MQ2 mq2(Analog_Input);

void setup(){
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
  mq2.begin();
}

void loop(){
  float* values= mq2.read(true);
  //lpg = values[0];
  lpg = mq2.readLPG();
  //co = values[1];
  co = mq2.readCO();
  //smoke = values[2];
  smoke = mq2.readSmoke();

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("LPG:");
  lcd.print(lpg);
  lcd.print(" CO:");
  lcd.print(co);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("SMOKE:");
  lcd.print(smoke);
  lcd.print(" PPM");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Please help me fix it so that it can perform just the same as the video. Thanks.

Comment: I want it to show this

LPG: 4  CO:2803
SMOKE: 16 PPM

on the LCD. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: blow the right amount of gas and smoke onto the sensor so that you get those readings

Answer (score 1):

First this should be like this:

```
float* values= mq2.read(false); //false
```

and then write this to be printed in the serial monitor

```
Serial.print('\n');
  Serial.print("LPG:");
  Serial.print(lpg);
  Serial.print(" CO:");
  Serial.print(co);

  Serial.print('\n');
  Serial.print("SMOKE:");
  Serial.print(smoke);
  Serial.print(" PPM");
  Serial.print('\n');
```